# Difference between isEqualTo: and isEqual:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods

What on earth is the difference between these methods?

Comment: Some quick searchin revels similar threads where people have discussed this kind of thing gin depth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112373/implementing-hash-isequal-isequalto-for-objective-c-collections

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`isEqual:` is part of the NSObject protocol and is meant for comparing objects.

`isEqualTo:` is part of the Cocoa AppleScript support infrastructure (specifically, [NSComparisonMethods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which allow AppleScript to compare Cocoa objects). It's normally the same as `isEqual:`, but can be overridden if you want equality to work differently internally and in a script.

Comment: What a trap :( I overwrote `isEqual(to:)` by accident, and has a test failure that took me a while to catch.

Answer (score 7):

`isEqualTo:` is part of the [NSComparisonMethods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/isEqualTo:) informal protocol, which also contains methods like `isGreaterThan:` and `isNotEqualTo:`, and is used for scripting support. And:

> The default implementation for this method provided by NSObject returns YES if an isEqualTo: message sent to the same object would return YES.

So when sending this message to an NSObject (or any subclass which does not override it) you will get the same behavior as `isEqual:`, however, you should be using `isEqual:` instead.

Comment: The documentation for `isEqualTo:` doesn't say that it's equivalent to `isEqual:`; it says that it's equivalent to sending `isEqualTo:` to the other object. It doesn't actually promise to use `isEqual:`, although I'm pretty sure it does. (Still, safer to just use `isEqual:` directly.) `isEqualTo:` is not merely “commonly used for scripting support”: That whole protocol *exists* for scripting support. It is commonly used for non-scripting purposes where `isEqual:` would be the more proper method.

Comment: It does say that the default implementation uses `isEqual:`.

Comment: Read it again. It says it uses `-isEqualTo:`. ;) Though I think that's just a typo.