# "If" statement mystery

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I've got an `if` routine that compares a value with two other values (using the || operator) and if the statement evaluates to `YES`, the value `firstActivity.stopTime` should change from `null` to the current time `[NSDate date]`.

However, it appears to evaluate to `NO`, resulting in no change, even though my `NSLog` readouts (and my own observations) appear to confirm that it would have to evaluate to `YES`.

Here's the code:

```
-(void) compareActivity
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    TimedActivity *firstActivity = [TimedActivity MR_findFirstOrderedByAttribute:@"startTime" ascending:NO];

    NSLog(@"1 Currently timed activity is %@",firstActivity.name);
    NSLog(@"2 thisSpec.activityOfInterest is %@",self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest);
    NSLog(@"3 Currently timed activity stopTime is %@",firstActivity.stopTime);
    NSLog(@"4 thisSpec.benchmarkActivity is %@",self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity);

    if (firstActivity.name == self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest || firstActivity.name == self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity)
    {
        firstActivity.stopTime = [NSDate date];
        [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        NSLog(@"5 Currently timed activity stopTime is %@",firstActivity.stopTime);
    }
    NSLog(@"6 Currently timed activity stopTime is %@",firstActivity.stopTime);
}
```

Here's the readout from the console:

```
2014-04-28 22:15:06.588 WMDGx[5683:a0b] 1 Currently timed activity is Test 1
2014-04-28 22:15:06.588 WMDGx[5683:a0b] 2 thisSpec.activityOfInterest is Test 1
2014-04-28 22:15:06.589 WMDGx[5683:a0b] 3 Currently timed activity stopTime is (null)
2014-04-28 22:15:06.589 WMDGx[5683:a0b] 4 thisSpec.benchmarkActivity is Test 2
2014-04-28 22:15:06.589 WMDGx[5683:a0b] 6 Currently timed activity stopTime is (null)
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I updated my code thusly:

```
if ([firstActivity.name isEqualToString:self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest] || [firstActivity.name isEqualToString:self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity])
{
    firstActivity.stopTime = [NSDate date];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    NSLog(@"5 Currently timed activity stopTime is %@",firstActivity.stopTime);
}
```

Now it works perfectly! Funny, I had run across this same issue once before some time back, and had actually tried changing the code, but this time I apparently did something wrong, leading me to think it was the wrong approach.

Many thanks!

Comment: so u are comparing string values better u can use something like `if ([firstActivity.name isEqualToString:self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest]|| [firstActivity.name isEqualToString: self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use `==` to compare object pointer, you need to use [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) to compare object

```
[firstActivity.name isEqual: self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest] || [firstActivity.name isEqual: self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity]
```

if they are `NSString`, you can use [`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the == to isEqualToString:

```
if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]){}
```

== for non-primitives such as NSString just compares the pointers (memory addresses), which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update above for my implementation of the previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isEqualTo:` instead of `==`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096691/difference-between-isequalto-and-isequal

Comment: @BryanChen But it can be used too

Comment: It is actually isEqual:

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pointer you need to convert `==` into [`isEqual:`] for validate the object

```
if (firstActivity.name isEqual self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest || firstActivity.name isEqual self.thisSpec.benchmarkActivity)
{
    firstActivity.stopTime = [NSDate date];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    NSLog(@"5 Currently timed activity stopTime is %@",firstActivity.stopTime);
}
```

if you are using the firstActivity.name and self.thisSpec.activityOfInterest are `NSString` then you need to validate using [`isEqualToString:`]

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update above for my implementation of the previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else has given the correct answer. Here's the explanation.

Objective-C grafts objects onto C by putting them beyond a pointer. What you're talking about with an `NSString *` is not formally a string, it is a pointer to a string, i.e. it is the memory address a string resides at. It describes the *identity* of a string, not the value.

So when you use `==` you are *comparing by identity not by value*. You're asking "do these two pointers point to the same description of a thing?".

You actually want to ask "do the two things at the end of these pointers have the same value?"

You can achieve that with `isEqual:` because most Foundation objects, and many others, implement that method to compare their *value* to the value of the parameter.

(aside: equality of identity implies equality of value but the converse isn't true; a common first test when implementing `isEqual:` in your own code is to check identity and possible be able to return `YES` without inspecting value)

Comment: I appreciate the in-depth answer! Please see my update above for my implementation of the previous answers.