# Object comparison using isEqual returning false only in 64 bit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, retina-display

In

```
for(ProductProperties *pP in productList)
    {
       if([pP.rangeList isEqual:selectedRangeobj])
       {
           [rangebasedPL addObject:pP];
       }

    }
```

the code `[pP.rangeList isEqual:selectedRangeobj]` returns `true` for every simulators in Xcode but for **iPad Retina (64 bit)** and **iPhone Retina (4 inch 64 bit)** it returns `false`. Is this a bug with 64 bit environment or what I have done wrong here?

rangeList and selectedRangeobj are defined as follows

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *rangeList;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * selectedRangeobj;
```

Comment: How are the `rangeList` property and `selectedRangeobj` defined? What are their values?

Comment: @MartinR - pls check the question now. I have added the info you asked .Pls let me knw if u need any other info too.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732065/comparing-two-nsmanagedobjects

Comment: So you compare a NSManagedObject with a NSMutableArray ? How can they ever be equal?

Comment: But in other simulators (other than 64 bit) its returning true.

Comment: With debugger you can check the values of the array objects and the one you compare them to.